# How to create/generate 3D molecular structure images?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration

I am interested in generating crystal structure images for my own research. I came across very cool and professional graphics:

[image]

Can someone please suggest some software to produce similar graphics (including the shadows behind the atoms)?

I should have contacted the owner directly, but I could not find any contact details on the website.

Comment: Yes, Blender and Maya might be options, but there _are_ others out there. Searching for chemistry, medicine, generating molecules models will give you some options. They can be a little fiddly to find, but they do exists. Also, there is a possibility that you _might_ be able to do this in SketchUpPro.

Comment: If you want to do it in Blender and you have any questions, there is community here in SE: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the ambient occlusion and reflections, this looks like it has been created using 3D modelling software like [3ds max](http://www.autodesk.co.uk/products/autodesk-3ds-max/overview), or [Maya](http://www.autodesk.co.uk/products/autodesk-maya/overview). However those are both industry-leading software packages and cost a **lot** (trust me). You might be better off trying to find a free solution, like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), or mimicking the effect in an illustration program like [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/illustrator.html).

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Just to mention, Inkscape is an open source Illustration program. http://www.inkscape.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 3D software, free one is [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)

[Example of complex structures](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PDB)